# Can't verify PGP signature for Swift installation

Tags: software-installation, gnupg

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.  I'm following the [Ubuntu Linux instructions](https://www.swift.org/download/) to install Swift. Currently on step 3.

In my Downloads directory, I have

```
swift-5.6.2-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04.tar.gz.sig
```

I ran this in my \Downloads:

```
gpg --verify swift-5.6.2-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04.tar.gz.sig
```

I receive this error:

```
gpg: no signed data
gpg: can't hash datafile: No data
```

I already imported the PGP keys into my keyring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you've moved the .tar.gz file containing Swift out of your Downloads directory, or it doesn't share a similar enough name. If the signature name is `swift-5.6.2-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04.tar.gz.sig`, the file name of the .tar.gz file must be `swift-5.6.2-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04.tar.gz`, and it must be in the same directory as your .sig file.

If the .tar.gz file has a different name, or if the .tar.gz file and the .sig file are in different directories, use this syntax:

```
gpg --verify /path/to/file.tar.gz.sig /other/path/to/data.tar.gz
```

Replace the paths accordingly.